# How to implement a function that returns an "enumeration" of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, collections, enumeration

I am working on a project about design patterns using Java. The class diagram before using the design patterns is provided in the link. Since I am new to Java, some of the classes methods descriptions is ambiguous for me.

For example in a class called `Mall` which has a method `stores()`, the method `stores()` is abstractly described as returning an "enumeration" of the stores in the mall (I'm using Java arrays as a placeholder in my example code).

I'd like to know what could be an "enumeration" in Java, i.e. what should I use for the concrete return type? In that particular case we are expected to use the **Iterator design pattern**. Please provide an example if possible.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kbug0ow3e14284b/DP_Project_1182.pdf?dl=0

```
public class Mall {
    private String mallId;
    private Store[] Stores;
    private Customer[] customers;

    public void enter(Customer c){}
    public void exit(Customer C){}
    public ShoppingCart getShopingCart()
    {
        return new ShoppingCart();
    }
    public Customer[] customers()
    {

    }
    public Store[] stores()
    {
    }
    void addStore(Store S)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: `java.util.Enumeration<T>` is an interface. Do you know the difference between an interface and a class in java? In the code you posted, method `stores()` returns an array of `Store` and not an enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an abstract class called Store as per your objective.
To return Enumeration of Iterator type, I have created a List and returned its elements as an Iterator.

I hope this example helps:

```
public abstract class Store {
    private String name;
    private Item items;
    //..other items
}
public class Mall {
    private Store myStore;
    //Vector which Stores all Store objects
    private List<Store> listOfStores=new LinkedList();
    //stores method which returns an Enumeration of Stores*/
    public Iterator<Store> stores(){
        return listOfStores.iterator();
    }
    public void addStore(Store s){
        listOfStores.add(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Vipul, Additional to Stefan comments, the question seems more oriented to the design pattern and not about implementing method returning an Enumerator. My recommendation when you try to reply a question is to be objective and interpret the questions that you have experience with before. for the questions asked I think it should follow recommendations like the patter example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern#Java ! Thanks for the collaboration and keep going!

Comment: Thanks for correction Stefan. Replaced obsolete Collection Vector and interface Enumeration with List and Iterator.

Comment: Iterator iter = mall.getCustomerList();